# foundation 5 (zurb) framework access forbidden on localhost xampp

Tags: php, zurb-foundation

i've downloaded the latest foundation 5 framework and tinkered with. i have made a simple website and saved the index with a php extension. the folder is saved in htdocs, the folder is named foundation5.

everytime i open it in the browser through localhost/foundation5. i've always welcomed with an access forbidden error 403. my other projects doesn't have errors like this.

i have tried saving it as a .html file and it worked. but with .php it doesn't work [image]

Comment: can You access another directories ?

Comment: @Subhanker yes i can access other directory other than this...

Comment: check if the dir contains any `.htaccess` file try deleting it.

Comment: it does not contain any

Comment: Try renaming the folder and check if error continues ?

Answer (score 0):

i've typed this command on the terminal and it solved the problem.

chmod -R 0777 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/foundation5